# How to concatenate non-consecutive columns using pivot in R

Tags: r, pivot

I am trying to pivot longer, collecting together using the following code:

```r
COHEN_Learning_Subset <- subset( VR_Data, select = c(25, 38, 42:46))
COHEN_Learning_Subset <- na.omit(COHEN_Learning_Subset)
COHEN_Learning_Subset <- pivot_longer(COHEN_Learning_Subset, cols = 4, 6:7,   
                                      names_to = "treatment", 
                                      values_to = "count")
```

For the life of me, I can't understand why it's not combining the columns. What might be going on?

Here is my data:

```r
structure(list(Relationship = c(4.33333349227905, 1, 4.33333349227905, 
3.33333325386047, 4.83333349227905, 3), Commission = c(300, 266.666656494141, 
258.333343505859, 308.333343505859, 333.333343505859, 250), Control = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), treatment_Shoes = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), treatment_Instructions_Only = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), treatment_Info_Only = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), treatment_Info_Instructions = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`4` = 4L, `5` = 5L, 
`6` = 6L, `8` = 8L, `11` = 11L, `14` = 14L, `15` = 15L, `16` = 16L, 
`21` = 21L, `23` = 23L, `24` = 24L, `27` = 27L, `28` = 28L, `29` = 29L, 
`30` = 30L, `36` = 36L, `37` = 37L, `40` = 40L, `41` = 41L, `46` = 46L, 
`47` = 47L, `48` = 48L, `49` = 49L, `50` = 50L, `51` = 51L, `53` = 53L, 
`55` = 55L, `58` = 58L, `59` = 59L, `60` = 60L, `61` = 61L, `62` = 62L, 
`63` = 63L, `64` = 64L, `66` = 66L, `68` = 68L, `72` = 72L, `74` = 74L, 
`75` = 75L, `76` = 76L, `77` = 77L, `78` = 78L, `82` = 82L, `83` = 83L, 
`84` = 84L, `85` = 85L, `86` = 86L, `87` = 87L, `90` = 90L, `91` = 91L, 
`93` = 93L, `94` = 94L, `95` = 95L, `97` = 97L, `98` = 98L, `101` = 101L, 
`102` = 102L, `103` = 103L, `104` = 104L, `106` = 106L, `112` = 112L, 
`113` = 113L, `115` = 115L, `116` = 116L, `119` = 119L, `120` = 120L, 
`122` = 122L, `124` = 124L, `125` = 125L, `126` = 126L, `127` = 127L, 
`128` = 128L, `129` = 129L, `131` = 131L, `133` = 133L, `134` = 134L, 
`135` = 135L, `139` = 139L, `140` = 140L, `141` = 141L, `142` = 142L, 
`147` = 147L, `148` = 148L, `149` = 149L, `151` = 151L, `153` = 153L, 
`156` = 156L, `157` = 157L, `158` = 158L, `160` = 160L, `226` = 226L, 
`227` = 227L, `228` = 228L, `229` = 229L, `230` = 230L, `236` = 236L, 
`238` = 238L, `239` = 239L, `242` = 242L, `246` = 246L, `248` = 248L, 
`249` = 249L, `250` = 250L, `256` = 256L, `258` = 258L, `260` = 260L, 
`261` = 261L, `264` = 264L, `266` = 266L, `268` = 268L, `270` = 270L, 
`271` = 271L, `272` = 272L, `275` = 275L, `276` = 276L, `279` = 279L, 
`280` = 280L, `282` = 282L, `283` = 283L, `284` = 284L, `285` = 285L, 
`289` = 289L, `291` = 291L, `292` = 292L, `293` = 293L, `294` = 294L, 
`298` = 298L, `299` = 299L, `301` = 301L, `302` = 302L, `303` = 303L, 
`306` = 306L, `307` = 307L, `308` = 308L, `309` = 309L, `312` = 312L, 
`314` = 314L, `316` = 316L, `318` = 318L, `319` = 319L, `320` = 320L, 
`324` = 324L, `325` = 325L, `327` = 327L, `330` = 330L, `331` = 331L, 
`332` = 332L, `334` = 334L, `335` = 335L, `338` = 338L, `343` = 343L, 
`344` = 344L, `346` = 346L, `349` = 349L, `350` = 350L, `352` = 352L, 
`353` = 353L, `357` = 357L, `360` = 360L, `361` = 361L, `364` = 364L, 
`365` = 365L, `366` = 366L, `367` = 367L, `368` = 368L, `369` = 369L, 
`371` = 371L, `372` = 372L, `373` = 373L, `374` = 374L, `375` = 375L, 
`378` = 378L, `379` = 379L, `382` = 382L, `384` = 384L, `385` = 385L, 
`386` = 386L, `448` = 448L, `459` = 459L, `460` = 460L, `461` = 461L, 
`462` = 462L, `463` = 463L, `464` = 464L, `465` = 465L, `466` = 466L, 
`467` = 467L, `468` = 468L, `469` = 469L, `470` = 470L, `471` = 471L, 
`472` = 472L, `473` = 473L, `474` = 474L, `475` = 475L, `476` = 476L, 
`477` = 477L, `478` = 478L, `479` = 479L, `480` = 480L, `481` = 481L, 
`482` = 482L, `483` = 483L, `484` = 484L, `485` = 485L, `486` = 486L, 
`487` = 487L, `488` = 488L, `489` = 489L, `490` = 490L, `491` = 491L, 
`492` = 492L, `493` = 493L, `494` = 494L, `495` = 495L, `496` = 496L, 
`497` = 497L, `498` = 498L, `499` = 499L, `500` = 500L, `501` = 501L, 
`502` = 502L, `503` = 503L, `504` = 504L, `505` = 505L, `506` = 506L, 
`507` = 507L, `508` = 508L, `509` = 509L, `510` = 510L, `511` = 511L, 
`512` = 512L, `513` = 513L, `514` = 514L, `515` = 515L, `516` = 516L, 
`517` = 517L, `518` = 518L, `519` = 519L, `520` = 520L, `521` = 521L, 
`522` = 522L, `523` = 523L, `524` = 524L, `525` = 525L, `526` = 526L, 
`527` = 527L, `528` = 528L, `529` = 529L, `530` = 530L, `531` = 531L, 
`532` = 532L, `533` = 533L, `534` = 534L, `535` = 535L, `536` = 536L, 
`537` = 537L, `538` = 538L, `539` = 539L, `540` = 540L, `541` = 541L, 
`542` = 542L, `543` = 543L, `544` = 544L, `545` = 545L, `546` = 546L, 
`547` = 547L, `548` = 548L, `549` = 549L, `550` = 550L, `551` = 551L, 
`552` = 552L, `553` = 553L, `554` = 554L, `555` = 555L, `556` = 556L, 
`557` = 557L, `558` = 558L, `559` = 559L, `560` = 560L, `561` = 561L, 
`562` = 562L, `563` = 563L, `564` = 564L, `565` = 565L, `566` = 566L, 
`567` = 567L, `568` = 568L, `569` = 569L, `570` = 570L, `571` = 571L, 
`572` = 572L, `573` = 573L, `574` = 574L, `575` = 575L, `576` = 576L, 
`577` = 577L, `578` = 578L, `579` = 579L, `580` = 580L, `581` = 581L, 
`582` = 582L, `583` = 583L, `584` = 584L, `585` = 585L, `586` = 586L, 
`587` = 587L, `588` = 588L, `589` = 589L, `590` = 590L, `591` = 591L, 
`592` = 592L, `593` = 593L, `594` = 594L, `595` = 595L, `596` = 596L, 
`597` = 597L, `598` = 598L, `599` = 599L, `600` = 600L, `601` = 601L, 
`602` = 602L, `603` = 603L, `604` = 604L, `605` = 605L, `606` = 606L, 
`607` = 607L, `608` = 608L, `609` = 609L, `610` = 610L, `611` = 611L, 
`612` = 612L, `613` = 613L, `614` = 614L, `615` = 615L, `616` = 616L, 
`617` = 617L, `618` = 618L, `619` = 619L, `620` = 620L, `621` = 621L, 
`622` = 622L, `623` = 623L, `624` = 624L, `625` = 625L, `626` = 626L, 
`627` = 627L, `628` = 628L, `629` = 629L, `630` = 630L, `631` = 631L, 
`632` = 632L, `633` = 633L, `634` = 634L, `635` = 635L, `636` = 636L, 
`637` = 637L, `638` = 638L, `639` = 639L, `640` = 640L, `641` = 641L, 
`642` = 642L, `643` = 643L, `644` = 644L, `645` = 645L, `646` = 646L, 
`647` = 647L, `648` = 648L, `649` = 649L, `650` = 650L, `655` = 655L, 
`656` = 656L, `657` = 657L, `658` = 658L, `659` = 659L, `660` = 660L, 
`663` = 663L, `664` = 664L, `665` = 665L, `667` = 667L, `670` = 670L, 
`672` = 672L, `673` = 673L, `674` = 674L, `675` = 675L, `676` = 676L, 
`677` = 677L, `679` = 679L, `681` = 681L, `682` = 682L, `684` = 684L, 
`685` = 685L, `687` = 687L, `688` = 688L, `690` = 690L, `691` = 691L, 
`693` = 693L, `694` = 694L, `695` = 695L, `697` = 697L, `699` = 699L, 
`702` = 702L, `703` = 703L, `704` = 704L, `706` = 706L, `709` = 709L, 
`710` = 710L, `711` = 711L, `712` = 712L, `715` = 715L, `716` = 716L, 
`717` = 717L, `721` = 721L, `722` = 722L, `726` = 726L, `728` = 728L, 
`729` = 729L, `732` = 732L, `734` = 734L, `735` = 735L, `736` = 736L, 
`738` = 738L, `739` = 739L, `740` = 740L, `741` = 741L, `742` = 742L, 
`746` = 746L, `747` = 747L, `748` = 748L, `750` = 750L, `752` = 752L, 
`753` = 753L, `754` = 754L, `755` = 755L, `757` = 757L, `759` = 759L, 
`760` = 760L, `762` = 762L, `764` = 764L, `765` = 765L, `766` = 766L, 
`767` = 767L, `768` = 768L, `769` = 769L, `771` = 771L, `773` = 773L, 
`775` = 775L, `777` = 777L, `779` = 779L, `780` = 780L, `782` = 782L, 
`783` = 783L, `785` = 785L, `787` = 787L, `788` = 788L, `789` = 789L, 
`790` = 790L, `791` = 791L, `792` = 792L, `793` = 793L, `794` = 794L, 
`796` = 796L, `797` = 797L, `798` = 798L, `799` = 799L, `800` = 800L, 
`802` = 802L, `805` = 805L, `810` = 810L, `811` = 811L, `812` = 812L, 
`813` = 813L, `815` = 815L, `816` = 816L, `817` = 817L, `818` = 818L, 
`819` = 819L, `823` = 823L, `824` = 824L, `825` = 825L, `826` = 826L, 
`827` = 827L, `829` = 829L, `830` = 830L, `831` = 831L, `832` = 832L, 
`834` = 834L, `835` = 835L, `836` = 836L, `837` = 837L, `838` = 838L, 
`839` = 839L, `840` = 840L, `841` = 841L, `842` = 842L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: So sorry about that Ronak. SO was not letting me post the question with the full amount of code. I think I may have solved the problem now but just adding in some Lorem Ipsum. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hm, it shouldn't be? I used dput(head(mydata) <- this is what I generally do to bring my data to SO. Is this not a recommended way?

Comment: Do you mean to use `cols = c(4, 6:7)` ? If not, what is your expected output?